# Persistent/Super procedure when web speed down

Tags: procedure, persistent, progress-4gl, openedge

I have a question regarding *persistent/super procedure* in **`openedge`**. If I run a procedure persistently, will that procedure still remain in the memory when my web speed is down or do I have to run it again ?

Answer (score 0):

A persistent procedure will end when the agent ends.  So if you restart webspeed, and therefore the agents, you will need to re-initialize the persistent procedure.

FWIW starting a persistent procedure on an agent might not be a very good idea to start with.  Especially if you do not understand their life cycle.